# How to calculate mask from TCP port range

Tags: tcp, range, port, mask

I'm trying to wrap my head around calculating a mask value which can denote L4 port range. Suppose the input range is 500-1000. Given the mask and lower value, how can the upper value be calculated?

Comment: Where have you come across TCP Port masks?

Comment: I'd never heard of them before. The only reference I can find is [AlliedTelesis Firewall documentation](http://www.alliedtelesis.com/userfiles/file/howto_config_hw_filters_x900.pdf)

Comment: @MattH It's exactly related to Firewalls. I'm working on Firewall implementation in a switch.The port range to match is input from CLI which is later added into Hardware through a chain of APIs. Sorry for being too vague and I'm doubtful if this can even be implemented. But I heard from someone the port range can be stored in the form a "value" and "mask". How is the question.

Comment: The document I linked has a detailed discussion of port masks.

Answer (score 2):

Port masking typically follows the format: `<port>/<mask>`. An example of port masking can be found in the OvS `ovs-ofctl` manual:

https://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs-2.5/ovs-ofctl.8.html

Excerpt:

```
...
       tcp_src=port/mask
       tcp_dst=port/mask
       udp_src=port/mask
       udp_dst=port/mask
       sctp_src=port/mask
       sctp_dst=port/mask
              Bitwise  match  on  TCP  (or  UDP or SCTP) source or destination
              port.  The port and mask are 16-bit numbers written  in  decimal
              or  in  hexadecimal prefixed by 0x.  Each 1-bit in mask requires
              that the corresponding bit in port must match.   Each  0-bit  in
              mask causes the corresponding bit to be ignored.

              Bitwise  matches  on transport ports are rarely useful in isola‐
              tion, but a group of them can be used to reduce  the  number  of
              flows  required  to  match  on  a range of transport ports.  For
              example, suppose that the goal is to match TCP source ports 1000
              to  1999,  inclusive.   One way is to insert 1000 flows, each of
              which matches on a single source port.  Another way is  to  look
              at the binary representations of 1000 and 1999, as follows:
              01111101000
              11111001111
              and  then  to  transform  those into a series of bitwise matches
              that accomplish the same results:
              01111101xxx
              0111111xxxx
              10xxxxxxxxx
              110xxxxxxxx
              1110xxxxxxx
              11110xxxxxx
              1111100xxxx
              which become the following when written in the  syntax  required
              by ovs-ofctl:
              tcp,tcp_src=0x03e8/0xfff8
              tcp,tcp_src=0x03f0/0xfff0
              tcp,tcp_src=0x0400/0xfe00
              tcp,tcp_src=0x0600/0xff00
              tcp,tcp_src=0x0700/0xff80
              tcp,tcp_src=0x0780/0xffc0
              tcp,tcp_src=0x07c0/0xfff0

              Only  Open  vSwitch  1.6  and later supports bitwise matching on
              transport ports.

              Like the exact-match forms described above,  the  bitwise  match
              forms apply only when dl_type and nw_proto specify TCP or UDP or
              SCTP.
```

The following python3 `mask_range` function returns a list of port masks given a start and end port number.

```py
# port_mask.py
LIMIT = 65535


def max_port(port, mask):
    xid = LIMIT - mask
    nid = port & mask
    return nid + xid


def port_mask(port, end):
    bit = 1
    mask = LIMIT
    test_mask = LIMIT
    net = port & LIMIT
    max_p = max_port(net, LIMIT)

    while net and max_p < end:
        net = port & test_mask
        if net < port:
            break
        max_p = max_port(net, test_mask)
        if max_p <= end:
            mask = test_mask
        test_mask -= bit
        bit <<= 1

    return mask


def mask_range(start, end):
    port_masks = []

    if end <= start or end > LIMIT:
        exit(1)

    port = start

    while port <= end:
        mask = port_mask(port, end)
        port_masks.append(f'{hex(port)}/{hex(mask)}')
        port = max_port(port, mask) + 1

    return port_masks
```

Example:

```py
# test.py
from port_mask import mask_range

if __name__ == '__main__':
    masks = mask_range(1000, 1999)
    print(f'1000-1999: {masks}')
```

Outputs:

```
1000-1999: ['0x3e8/0xfff8', '0x3f0/0xfff0', '0x400/0xfe00', '0x600/0xff00', '0x700/0xff80', '0x780/0xffc0', '0x7c0/0xfff0']
```